# Is there a pre-2011 public version of USA's Social Security Death Master File?

Tags: data-request, usa

I am trying to find an old version of the Social Security Master Death file. Specifically, one that has a county or residence zip code. The only public source for the full file that seems to continuously pop up is this: http://ssdmf.info/download.html

Unfortunately, it does not have the geographic information that I require as it is too recent.

I have tried to scrape some of the websites that list the geographic information. However, the process is very lengthy. Furthermore, their location search filters do not always function well. Recently, I tried to find the number of deaths in a given county for certain years. While some results made sense, others were way off of what they could realistically be.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

mortality multiple cause files?

http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data_access/vitalstatsonline.htm

accessible via

http://wonder.cdc.gov/cmf-ICD10.html
or
http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20vital%20statistics%20system%20%28nvss%29

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I specifically need Social Security data as I want to compare the differences between it and CDC at the county level!